# How to use NSPredicate for Key-Path values

Tags: iphone, cocoa, nspredicate, objective-c

Using an NSPredicate for an array is rather straight forward using filteredArrayUsingPredicate:.

How is this done for key-path values? Meaning, I have an array of objects (in this case, the objects are of the same type). The objects each have an instance variable called name. As per the documentation, it says to do the following:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
   @"ANY employees.firstName like 'Matthew'"];
```

Is that -also- used in filteredArrayUsingPredicate? What if I have an array of People objects? does that mean I would use:

```
NSArray *allPeopleObjects; // pre-populated
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY people.name like 'Foo'"];
NSArray *matching = [allPeopleObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Documentation is a bit lacking in that department.

Is it also possible to use the Predicate against a single Person object? Something such as Person.name contains[cd] 'Foo'? How would that be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, both of your examples will work perfectly. `NSPredicate` can follow key value paths. If you have a single `Person` object, why wouldn't you just use `valueForKeyPath:` and do the comparison in code instead of using an `NSPredicate`? It seems like overkill in that case.

Comment: Alex, I'm not exactly sure what to pass valueForKeyPath against a single Person object. I mean, I can use NSRange, but I was wondering if I can do something like [person valueForKeyPath:@"name like foo"] type code.

Comment: `[[person valueForKeyPath:@"name"] rangeOfString:@"Matthew"].position != NSNotFound`